# Memory Leak.. ABContactsHelper

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, memory-leaks

The instruments shows following memory leak & I cannot figure out how to solve it.

[image: Memory Leak]

Any ideas ?? I am using ARC base target 5.0 with -fno-objc-arc flags for this library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751867/memory-leak-loading-thumbnail-image

Comment: i still can't figure out from that. I am releasing memory appropriately but where's the leak. :/

Comment: Don't you need to `autorelease` image, if you're not using ARC?

Comment: isn't the image created `autorelease`d with `imageWithData` method.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this piece of code. But the caller (or someone else) is over-retaining the returning `UIImage` object. You should check all the references to it.

Comment: The memory of `CGDataRef` seems to release fine, however, there seems to be some leaks which point to this very line as shown in images below.